# Multidimensional integral of even fnunction

Tags: real-analysis

I'm to prove the following, which appears in the generalization of the Gaussian to several dimensions:

$  \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} exp(-\frac{1}{2}z^{T}\Sigma^{-1}z) \ z \ dz = 0 $

Note that $z$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and the integral is taken over all of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. The zero is the right hand side is the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, i.e. $(0,...0)$.

$\Sigma$ is a positive definite matrix.

My textbook says it is due to the "evenness" of the exponent. I don't fully understand what that means and how it is being applied in this example. Thoughts?

Comment: Try to use the "substitution" $z \to -z$. What do you get? :)

Comment: P.s. The exponent is even, but there is a one more $z$ term in the integral which is the one that makes the total function an ODD function. Thus, the integral of an odd function (from $-a$ to $+a$) is zero. In your case you're in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which means lots of symmetric integrals ($n$ ones).